# How to fix stale index statistics

Tags: oracle

We have some stale stats for indexes, which we can see by using the query below:

```
select * from all_ind_statistics
where  index_name in ('DEPT_FK_BX01','DEPT_FK_BX02')
and    table_owner = 'GDC_ADMIN'
and    stale_stats = 'YES';
```

To fix the stale stats we have run:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats
    ( ownname => 'GDC_ADMIN'
    , tabname => 'DEPT_TABLE'
    , cascade => DBMS_STATS.AUTO_CASCADE
    , degree  => NULL );
end;
```

but still stale stats exists.

Is there any way to fix the stale stats?

Comment: How did you trigger "Collect Stats on complete table"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit.. Thanks a lot for the reply..  

Exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=> 'GDC_ADMIN', tabname=> 'DEPT_TABLE', CASCADE=>DBMS_STATS.AUTO_CASCADE, DEGREE=>NULL);

Comment: What you're doing *should* work.  Is there anything unusual about those tables and indexes?  For example, is the table reference partitioned?  (In which case the index may be owned by the parent table instead of the child table.)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider gathering statistics with `cascade=>TRUE` option :

```
SQL> exec Dbms_Stats.Gather_Table_Stats('GDC_ADMIN','DEPT',cascade=>TRUE);
```

to collect all index and column statistics associated with the specified table.

Answer (score 0):

execute dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(ownname => 'GDC_ADMIN', indname =>'DEPT_FK_BX01', estimate_percent =>DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE);

and etc.